# Change background color of an android actionbar, base tutorial

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the ActionBar color of a *New Android Application made by Eclipse wizard* following the android tutorial ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground)), but i got several problems.

I set minSdkVersion to 10 (it should be android 2.1 or so).

When i paste this code into themes.xml (as said by the tutorial):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Eclipse give to me those errors:

- line 5: android:actionBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is
  10)
- line 8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given
  name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
- line 16: error: Error: No resource found
  that matches the given name: attr 'background'.

I modded little things (Base theme and Color), however the clean code is in the tutorial.

My Styles.xml is here:

```
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: do you reference app compact in your android project?

Comment: can you post code how u solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use action bar below api level 11 you need to reference app compact (from the support library) in your project.

Your class needs to extends `ActionBarActivity` and you need to use `Theme.AppCompat`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Also check this

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Or you need to use `ActionBarSherlock`

http://actionbarsherlock.com/